# test1 alert appears, test2 alert doesn't - invalid regex between them?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
alert('test1');
var re = new RegExp("(http://(?:[A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)?[A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+/?)", "si");
alert('test2');
```

Why is this happening? How to solve this problem?

Comment: s doesn't work. I saw it at http://www.webreference.com/js/column5/modifiers.html

Comment: That page explains that /s, /m and /x don't work in IE 4.0, which is true although newer versions of IE support the /m modifier.  Javascript only allows /g, /i and /m.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "s" is the problem, it's not a valid modifier for javascript regular expressions.  The only valid modifiers are /g (global) /i (case-insensitive) and /m (multi-line).